# Unrooting Stratospehre

Tags: samsung, unrooting, verizon

I have a Stratosphere that I rooted a while back, but ever since, it has not been able to perform a system update. It would restart and everything, but then the update notification would still be there.

I tried [unrooting](http://theunlockr.com/2013/03/17/how-to-unroot-the-samsung-stratosphere/) it, which at least got rid of the warning symbol when it boots, but it's still stuck on 2.3.5. (Although the update notification has disappeared).

I [checked if it was still rooted](http://www.androidcentral.com/is-my-phone-rooted), and ConnectBot still lets be do su, so it looks like the unroot didn't work.

Why can't I unroot?